# Converting variable name to string in SAS/IML

Tags: sas

I have a variable called "var" in SAS/IML.  I want to know how I can create a new string variable:

```
var2 = "var";
```

In other words how do I take the name of any variable and convert it to a string.

Comment: Does the `vname()` function work in `IML`? That's seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the [name()](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/59656/HTML/default/viewer.htm#langref_sect178.htm) function is what you want.

```
proc iml;
  var=1;
  var2=name(var);
  print var var2;
quit;
```

/*in output */

```
 var var2

   1 var
```